# Retrieving ALL DBpedia Resource properties

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

I am using this SPARQL query to retrieve all properties for a resource, for example the resource is http://dbpedia.org/resource/Suez this query doesn't retrieve all properties in http://dbpedia.org/page/Suez, I understand that the page is different than the resource.

How can I retrieve all properties in the html page ??

Here is my query without the prefixes:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?property ?Label  
WHERE 
{ 
    { 
      <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Suez> ?property ?o .
    } union 
    {
       ?o ?property  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Suez>  
    } 
    ?property rdfs:label ?Label.  
    FILTER (lang(?Label) = 'en').  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't mention which properties you're not seeing, but you're requiring that each of the properties actually *has* a value for **rdfs:label**, and not all of them do.  For instance, this query returns 16 results:

```sql
select distinct ?property {
  { dbr:Suez ?property ?o }
  union
  { ?s ?property dbr:Suez }

  filter not exists { ?property rdfs:label ?label }
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20%3Fproperty%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20dbr%3ASuez%20%3Fproperty%20%3Fo%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20union%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%3Fs%20%3Fproperty%20dbr%3ASuez%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20filter%20not%20exists%20%7B%20%3Fproperty%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20%7D%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

You'd need to update your query to check whether the properties have a label, and then take the English label if it has one:

```sql
select distinct ?property ?label {
  { dbr:Suez ?property ?o }
  union
  { ?s ?property dbr:Suez }

  optional { 
    ?property rdfs:label ?label .
    filter langMatches(lang(?label), 'en')
  }
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20%3Fproperty%20%3Flabel%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20dbr%3ASuez%20%3Fproperty%20%3Fo%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20union%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%3Fs%20%3Fproperty%20dbr%3ASuez%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20optional%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fproperty%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20filter%20langMatches%28lang%28%3Flabel%29%2C%20%27en%27%29%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: Yes It was the label issue, I checked the count returned by your suggested query against the count of properties in the page and they are almost the same, may be one or two still messing but the properties I need are there so I will accept the answer , Thank You

Comment: If you mention which properties, we might be able to figure out why they're not appearing.  I'm not sure offhand what this would miss...

Answer (score 0):

Following sparql query will display all the properties and values of the resource [Suez](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Suez).

```
select distinct ?property ?value{
  dbr:Suez ?property ?value
}
```

[SPARQL Results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20%3Fproperty%20%3Fvalue%7B%0D%0A%20%20dbr%3ASuez%20%3Fproperty%20%3Fvalue%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

You can compare the results of above query with the actual resource properties available via any web browser using the [link Suez](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Suez).

Please note as follows about the results of above query:

1. A property with multiple values will be displayed multiple times. For example the property 'dct:subject' has eight different values and hence will be displayed eight times in the result.
2. "dbo:abstract" will be displayed multiple times in the result for abstract in different languages.

Hope it helps.

Cheers,
Ambi.